# Background color not applying on resize/restore down window

Tags: html, css

Following is the code of my header. The problem is I set the background of my header to `#444` and width:100%, when i open the website in maximize window then the header appears as expected but when i view the site in resize window then the header background color limits itself to the resize window size and not when i scroll right. Kindly let me know how to fix this issue so my color applys to the whole header.

[image]

```
#hea {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2C3033;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
    border-top: 1px solid #0C0E0F;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    height: 55px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


.rap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
}

<div id="hea">
    <div class="rap">

        <span style="margin-top:4px;" id="slogan"><img alt="Logo" src="Logo3.png"></span><!-- end of #slogan -->


        <ul id="navy">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>


        </ul><!-- end of #navigation -->




    </div><!-- end of .wrapper -->
</div>
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/hA7gitR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

I have to add `min-width;` css property to my header's csscode